# Input box with two values as inputs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this code that asks for a key to open a certain window form. If the number of invalid keys is larger than 3, the application ends.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load




        Dim clave As String, attempts As Integer, intentoclave As String

        'This is the key

        clave = "UNI"
        attempts = 0


        For attempts = 1 To 4


            If attempts < 4 Then
                intentoclave = InputBox("Write the key")

                If intentoclave = clave Then
                    Exit For

                    Me.Show()
                End If
            Else
                End
            End If

        Next



    End Sub
```

It's working OK, but I would like to enter the name of the user as well in the input box. How Can I do that?

Comment: AFAIK, getting two values from one input box is not directly possible. You can ask the user to enter both values in a specific format (e.g. "username:key") and then split the response and check both values, or create a new form with the two fields.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? WPF? WinForms? You can always create you own form and use `ShowDialog` (in WinForms) to do this.

Comment: Window Form. I'll find out about ShowDialog

Answer (score 0):

The [InputBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/6z0ak68w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has optional values:

```
Public Function InputBox( _
   ByVal Prompt As String, _
   Optional ByVal Title As String = "", _
   Optional ByVal DefaultResponse As String = "", _
   Optional ByVal Xpos As Integer = -1, _
   Optional ByVal YPos As Integer = -1 _
) As String
```

You did not specify how the username is retrieved nor where you want to display it but if you want to display it as the default value of the input box, all you need to do is to pass that username to the third parameter (DefaultResponse ) of the InputBox function:

```
intentoclave = InputBox("Write the key", "Any title", "Your username goes here!")
```

Comment: I meant that the input box has to ask for two values: Key and Username. In my code it only asks for the key. Maybe the input box doesn't let that. So , there's another way?

Comment: I you want to ask for 2 different values, I don't think the InputBox is the right way to do it.  You may display 2 subsequent InputBox, or you could create a window of you own (depending on the technology used (WinForm / WPF).